# After Card displaying, how to continue waterfall dialog flow in sdk v4.4

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am referring sample code and tried simple scenario to display card.
How to continue waterfall_Dialog after card display?

I am referring sample code 05.multi-turn-prompt and 06.using-cards - (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt/dialogs/userProfileDialog.js)

```
      ...this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
        this.initialData.bind(this), 
        this.displayCard.bind(this),    
        this.text.bind(this)
    ])); ...

async run(turnContext, accessor) {
   ...}

async initialData(step) {
    return await step.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, `Type anything to display card`);
} 

async displayCard(step) {
   await step.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [this.createAdaptiveCard()]});                
}

async text(step) {
    console.log("step.res"+step.context.activity.text);
    await step.context.sendActivity("Thank you for selecting an option");

}
```

---

```
async displayCard(step) {
   await step.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [this.createAdaptiveCard()]});                
  return await this.text(step);
}
```

To display card and continue waterfall Dialog.

After display of card it should continue the flow and display "Thank you for selecting an option",

1. But it is going to Begin_Dialog and asking for " Type anything to display card"
2. If I try other approach by call the next dialog. 
   I get "Oops. Something went wrong!"
   "[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

To advance to the next dialog step you need to call NextAsync following the step that includes the card.

For example,

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> StartSelectionStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Set the user's age to what they entered in response to the age prompt.
    var userProfile = (UserProfile)stepContext.Values[UserInfo];
    userProfile.Age = (int)stepContext.Result;

    if (userProfile.Age < 25)
    {
        // If they are too young, skip the review selection dialog, and pass an empty list to the next step.
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
            MessageFactory.Text("You must be 25 or older to participate."),
            cancellationToken);
        return await stepContext.NextAsync(new List<string>(), cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, start the review selection dialog.
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ReviewSelectionDialog), null, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In the above snippet, if the user is not of the correct age a message is displayed saying as much. `return await stepContext.NextAsync()` is called which advances the dialog to the next step. If the user is of age, then a new dialog is begun ("ReviewSelectionDialog"). The snippet comes from the docs on "Create advanced conversation flow using branches and loops", located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), that you can reference.

Hope of help!

Comment: I tired using `return await step.next();`. Now i am able to continue the flow, but bot is not waiting for user input. Before clicking of **button**, bot goes to next waterfall_Dialog.

Comment: Add `return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting }` (adjust as needed) to the end of the user input step. This will pause the dialog until user input is entered.

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine for me, but is this good practice? to make status as waiting by adjusting it's value

Comment: Yes. From the doc's library [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogturnstatus?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_DialogTurnStatus_Waiting): DialogTurnStatus.Waiting "Indicates that the dialog on top is waiting for a response from the user."

Answer (score 0):

Here, I attach the code of multiple dialog sets. you just **need to register dialog in dialog set** before begin or replace dialogs.

> **this.flowBuilderDialog** and **this.faqDialog** is the dialog objects and **DialogsNameList.FLOW_BUILDER_DIALOG** and **DialogsNameList.FAQ_DIALOG** are name of the dialogs.

```
class GreetingDialog extends ComponentDialog {
constructor(dialogId, userInfoPropertyAccessor, flowNextQuestionAccessor, flowBuilderConversationAccessor, flowBuilderDialog, faqDialog) {
    super(dialogId);

    if (!userInfoPropertyAccessor) throw new Error(`[MainDialog]: Missing parameter \'userInfoPropertyAccessor\' is required`);
    if (!flowBuilderDialog) throw new Error(`[MainDialog]: Missing parameter \'flowBuilderDialog\' is required`);
    if (!faqDialog) throw new Error(`[MainDialog]: Missing parameter \'faqDialog\' is required`);
    // Define the greeting dialog and its related components.

    let greetingChoicePrompt = new ChoicePrompt(GREETING_CHOICE_PROMPT);
    greetingChoicePrompt.style = ListStyle.heroCard;

    this.addDialog(greetingChoicePrompt)
        .addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(GREETING_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.introStep.bind(this),
            this.actStep.bind(this),
            this.finalStep.bind(this)
        ]));

    this.flowBuilderDialog = flowBuilderDialog;
    this.faqDialog = faqDialog;

    this.initialDialogId = GREETING_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    this.flowNextQuestionAccessor = flowNextQuestionAccessor;
    this.flowBuilderConversationAccessor = flowBuilderConversationAccessor;
}

/**
 * The run method handles the incoming activity (in the form of a TurnContext) and passes it through the dialog system.
 * If no dialog is active, it will start the default dialog.
 * @param {*} turnContext
 * @param {*} accessor
 */

async run(turnContext, accessor) {
    const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
    dialogSet.add(this);
    dialogSet.add(this.flowBuilderDialog);
    dialogSet.add(this.faqDialog);

    const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);

    const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
    if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
        await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
    }
}


async introStep(stepContext) {
    return await stepContext.prompt(GREETING_CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: 'How can I help you today?',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(['Flow Builder', 'FAQ'])
    });
}

async actStep(stepContext) {
    console.log("Step: Result", stepContext.result);

    switch (stepContext.result.value) {
        case 'Flow Builder':
            await this.flowNextQuestionAccessor.set(stepContext.context, 0);
            await this.flowBuilderConversationAccessor.set(stepContext.context, '');
            return await stepContext.replaceDialog(DialogsNameList.FLOW_BUILDER_DIALOG);
        case 'FAQ':
            return await stepContext.replaceDialog(DialogsNameList.FAQ_DIALOG);
    }
}

async finalStep(stepContext) {
    return await stepContext.replaceDialog(this.initialDialogId, {restartMsg: 'What else can I do for you?'});
}
```

}